# Python typing: pylance doesn't show input types

Tags: python, wrapper, python-typing

I'm trying to do "wrapper" class for any callable. Here is minimal example:

```
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Generic, Callable

ReturnType = TypeVar("ReturnType", bound=Any)
CallableType = Callable[..., ReturnT]


class Wrapper(Generic[ReturnType]):
    def __init__(self, callable_: CallableType[ReturnType]) -> None:
        self.callable_ = callable_

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> ReturnType:
        return self.callable_(*args, **kwargs)


class Action:
    def __init__(self, title: str) -> None:
        """docstring"""
        self.title = title


wrapped = Wrapper(Action)

action = wrapped("title")
```

Pylance can understand, that `action` type is `Action`, but I can't see `__init__` docsting and needed arguments:[image: pylance help string]

Desired behaviour:[image]

What do I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Using [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) and making `Wrapper` generic also in terms of the parameter types should work. See this [Mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=4179b4baa78001b330a22de1a070e7f4)...

Comment: ...and [this Pyright playground](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?gzip=H4sIAFF-mWQC_3VRwU7DMAy95yusntKq9AMqgYQ4cJuqguCAUBQ6b4pI08gNTPt73DRtGWK52HnOe892DjT0EM7euCOY3g8U4EFbqz8slvCIDsl0JTSadP_kkdPns8cXTUI0cLvhMmuyXLQMpbrMWgaE6KweR3gl7T2STIJvTQnte14L4LPHAyhlnAlKyRHtoYQudaDqtZlEgZs72A0OZ-p0Jka1EriBNRe_5CdwlS80HccammqKfC0-TwsyZ9Gm3TwIwxe5P1ayuKRv0953wQzu6nTBBIs1jIGujRNf8Cgxsuwprm_PyLLI2SIXhN-oreIPRJle_QtWywq4Sx25LJZqMos-2SVRJ4cfFf1dZSECAAA%3D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've annotated your `__call__` with `Any`. Pyright doesn't restrict these `Any` to more narrow types just based on your usage. You'll need to use a [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) to capture the parameters of the callable you accept as the argument (similar how you capture the return type with a TypeVar).

```
from typing import Any, TypeVar, ParamSpec, Generic, Callable

Params = ParamSpec("Params")
ReturnType = TypeVar("ReturnType")


class Wrapper(Generic[Params, ReturnType]):
    def __init__(self, callable_: Callable[Params, ReturnType]) -> None:
        self.callable_ = callable_

    def __call__(self, *args: Params.args, **kwargs: Params.kwargs) -> ReturnType:
        return self.callable_(*args, **kwargs)


class Action:
    def __init__(self, title: str) -> None:
        """docstring"""
        self.title = title


wrapped = Wrapper(Action)

action = wrapped("title")
```

Note1: If you're using python<3.10 you'll need to import `ParamSpec` from `typing_extensions`.

Note2: You don't need to pass a `bound=Any` to the TypeVar as that's (more or less) the default anyway. Passing `bound=Any` doesn't change anything nevertheless.

Comment: You won't be able to keep the docstring though as far as I know...
If `Wrapper` is a decorator there may be a special case to keep the docstring in such a case.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I can see docstring